# How to connect macmini with my iphone 4s with iOS6 beta using core bluetooth framework?

Tags: iphone, ios6, core-bluetooth

How to use core CBPeripheralManager to broadcast and receive advertisement for ios6..

Comment: iOS 6 is still under NDA and you are not allowed to talk about it outside of the official Apple Developers Forums.

Comment: CBPeripheralManager can be used for advertising your device as peripheral to other centrals. But you can't use it to "receive advertisement".